# How do I control the tick label size in flot

Tags: flot, graphing

I have a basic bar chart I'm presenting in flot (5 bars, displaying the % per status).

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), [
    {
        label: 'Failed',
        data: [[0,10]],
        bars: { show: true }
    },
    {
        label: 'Passed',
        data: [[1,15]],
        bars: { show: true }
    },
    {
        label: 'Not Run',
        data: [[2,30]],
        bars: { show: true }
    },
    {
        label: 'Blocked',
        data: [[3,5]],
        bars: { show: true }
    },
    {
        label: 'In Progress',
        data: [[4,40]],
        bars: { show: true }
    }
],
{
    xaxis: {
        ticks: [[0.5, "Failed"], [1.5, "Passed"], [2.5, "Not Run"], [3.5, "Blocked"], [4.5, "In Progress"]]
    },
    legend: {
        show: false
    }
});
```

I'm finding the font used for the tick values on the x axis are a little too big, especially when the graph is displayed at small dimensions ie. 240x100.  I've read the API documentation, but can't find how to control the tick label sizes.

Is this possible OOTB?

Comment: Any chance you could post the updated and corrected solution? I tried adding this 'grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: false, .tickLabel { font-size: 80% } },' to my chart but it bombs out.

Comment: You need to add .tickLabel to your app's cascading style sheet (CSS), not as part of the json you pass to the flot call.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It doesn't appear you can set the font size via the API, but you can use css to set the size of the tick labels.

```
.tickLabel { font-size: 80% }
```

Comment: Yeah I discovered this myself but forgot to followup by closing this question.  The CSS changes have some "interesting" effects in IE when zooming a page up to say 120% unfortunately - though IE isn't a great candidate for flot at the best of times really!

Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: where should i make this change @BrentM

Comment: @madLokesh in your CSS file.

Comment: Also you can control y or x label :
`.flot-y-axis .tickLabel { font-size: 9px }`
`.flot-x-axis .tickLabel { font-size: 12px }`

Comment: For people looking how to do it via the API nevertheless, have a look at the other answer of @Shun Takeda

Answer (score 12):

Here's an example directly from the API:

```
xaxis:{
   font:{
      size:11,
      style:"italic",
      weight:"bold",
      family:"sans-serif",
      variant:"small-caps"
   }
}
```

http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt

Answer (score 6):

The above two answers won't work on the latest version of flot, as they no longer use 'real' text (the text is drawn instead). Instead specify these options:

`{xaxis: {font: size: some_number}, yaxis: {font: size: some_number}}`

(replace `some_number` with the desired size in points)

Comment: [For compatibility with Flot 0.7 and earlier the labels are also given the 'tickLabel' class, but this is deprecated and scheduled to be removed with the release of version 1.0.0](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes)

Comment: Also, the latest version still uses 'real' text by default. Once you include the 'canvas' plugin the default seems to switch (which doesn't seem to be documented).

Answer (score 1):

I used the following:

**CSS File/SCSS File**

```
#graph_label .tickLabel{

     font-size: 50%;
  }
```

**Index.html or place where you are plotting the graph area**

```
$.plot($("graph_label"), [dataArrayReference], options);
```

*Ref: @BrentM 's Answer Above*

**PS: I am using Flot Version prior to 0.8.1 so I dont have any idea about how latest version would work**